# Instance with New Operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was trying to comprehend the vue js boiler plate code from the cli.

Inside App.js, they have done something like this

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

According to the [explanation on freeCodeCamp](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-vue-handbook-a-thorough-introduction-to-vue-js-1e86835d8446)

> we create the Vue instance, by assigning it to the DOM element
>   identified by #app, which we defined in index.html, and we tell it to
>   use the App component.

Here, he said the we create a new instance. So I googled about creating an [instance in JS (using new keyword)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

And Almost all the example they have looks like this

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);

console.log(car1.make);
```

With following explanation

> new operator lets developers create an instance of a user-defined
>   object type or of one of the built-in object types

The definition I think is relatively not that hard to comprehend

Now my question is that in Vue.js, why have we done `new Vue({`, like why do we have `{` inside `(`

Is it because say our Vue function constructor wants on object instead of strings, number?

Or is there any other significance?

Comment: yes, exactly, it's just a design choice on Vue's part -- a good one, if I may add, given how many possible options there are (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data, ff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because say our Vue function constructor wants on object instead of strings, number?

Yes

> Or is there any other significance?

No

Answer (score 0):

It's as you suggest. The Vue instantiator expects an object as argument.